# How to create the scatter plot with 3 different columns in one view with secondary axis or dual axis like excel in TABLEAU?

Tags: tableau-desktop

I have the following data ( attached excel) which has 4 columns where 3 columns are used for the scatters and another is used for the x-axis with distinct count of Owned. I can able to do that in excel but how to do that in tableau?

I'm attaching data with and respective screenshot to what I want to ..

I want to plot this 3 columns same as below

[image]

I can do this in excel by this way

[image]

How can I do this in tableau? I connected to snowflake with client server when I'm trying to find out the solution it is asking that for pivot table option but not able to get that as per this [answer](https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D54T00000C62I3SAJ/how-do-i-add-multiple-scatter-plots-onto-the-same-view?t=1702670990948).

Thanks...!